# How to trim an xml variable

Tags: xml

I have this xml file that is feeding a receipt in RMS.  I wanted to know if there is a way to trim the trailing spaces after the variable

```
<IF>
   <CONDITION> (Receipt.TaxSystem = taxsystemVAT) &amp; (Entry.Taxable = 0) </CONDITION>
    <THEN>
      <SET name="ExtendedExclsvPricePlusDiscount" type="vbcurrency">  Entry.ExtendedExclsvPrice + Entry.ExtendedDiscount </SET> 
     <ROW> Entry.Item.ItemLookupCode "|" Entry.Description "|" ExtendedExclsvPricePlusDiscount         </ROW>
    </THEN>
    <ELSE>
    <ROW> Entry.Item.ItemLookupCode "|" Entry.Description "|" Entry.ExtendedFullPrice       </ROW>
    </ELSE>
</IF>
```

I am tring to trim the entry.description field.

Comment: Where are you reading the file? You can do that using XPath (`normalize-space()`) or some `trim()` function you might have in your host language. XML alone can't do that.

Comment: I am using Microsoft dynamics RMS ... The code is really locked down so I can't open that up.. This "template" is the only thing they allow us to change

Comment: The XML is just a data structure. As far as the XML document is concerned, those spaces are significant. After you extract the data you want (using XPath, JavaScript, or whatever means you have to do that), you can trim it.